# SQL beginner, syntax error with WHERE

Tags: sqlite

I'm sorry, but I don't find the problem. Can somebody help me please?

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS" (
  "id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "deviceaddress"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "devicename"  TEXT,
  "username"    TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE "MESSAGES" (
  "id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "from"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "to"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "body"    TEXT NOT NULL,
  "time"    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY("to") REFERENCES "USERS"("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY("from") REFERENCES "USERS"("id")
)
```

Now I want all messages with to = 1:

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE to  = 1;
```

And I get a syntax error near "to". Why???

Regards Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems compounding each other. First, you are using reserved words `to` and `from` (and also `time`) as your table columns, which is generally a bad idea. You have resolved that problem by quoting the questionable identifiers:

```
  "from"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "to"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

Now you forget that from there on you must *always* quote these identifiers. In other words, to fix your second problem your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE "to"  = 1
```

However, you really should kill both these problems with one solution by *not* using reserved words as identifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGES (
  id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  from_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  to_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
...
```

This way you'll never need to remember to quote them.